# Windows Form Fullscreen

Tags: c#, forms, windows-forms-designer

I am having an issue getting my forms application to go fullscreen.

```
this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1080);
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

My window is borderless, my issue is that it appears to not be the proper resolution ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFcoM.jpg)) I want this to take up the entire screen. My screen resolution is 1920x1080, and I have already tried setting the Bounds to the bounds of the screen, it makes no difference.

If I set the window state to minimized, then again to maximized it goes true fullscreen, but all my elements do not scale with it, and this messes up some positioning math.

Is there a solution?

Comment: WPF does a better job with resizing than Windows Forms.  You may need to write some code to adjust things based on the size of the window

Answer (score 3):

You might be doing too much. This works for me:

FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;

SetBounds(0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

Comment: A friend has pointed out that, because the laptop I am using is a touch screen (Yoga), it may have issues with resolutions because of the "infinite resolution" this laptop has. Basically, it is not really 1080p.

Comment: It is most likely just a high-dpi display. Try putting all of your controls on a Panel, then center dock it on the form. WinForms will scale to high-dpi if done correctly.